# Array List trouble

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently making a paint program and am implementing the undo and redo function. So far, if I remove the code for the redo part, it works, but for some reason, if I add the redo code back in, it just throws a arrayOutOfIndex exception or NullPointer. I have tried everything, and do not know what else there is to do!

Sorry if this problem is painstakingly easy; I am just a beginner.

Code:

```
    public void redo()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){

        if(redo[0].get(0)!=null){
            al.add((Shape) redo[0].get(redo[0].size()-1));
            cl.add((Color) redo[1].get(redo[1].size()-1));
            tl.add((Integer) redo[2].get(redo[2].size()-1));
            lineEnd.add((Integer) redo[3].get(redo[3].size()-1));
            junction.add((Component) redo[4].get(redo[4].size()-1));
        }

    redo[0].remove(redo[0].size()-1);
    redo[1].remove(redo[1].size()-1);
    redo[2].remove(redo[2].size()-1);
    redo[3].remove(redo[3].size()-1);
    redo[4].remove(redo[4].size()-1);
    }
    repaint();

}
public void undo()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){

        Shape alComponent = al.get(al.size()-1);
        Color clComponent = cl.get(cl.size()-1);
        Integer tlComponent = tl.get(tl.size()-1);
        Integer lineEndComponent = lineEnd.get(lineEnd.size()-1);
        Integer junctionComponent = juncture.get(juncture.size()-1);

        if(al.get(0)!=null){
            redo[0].add(alComponent);
            redo[1].add(clComponent);
            redo[2].add(tlComponent);
            redo[3].add(lineEndComponent);
            redo[4].add(junctionComponent);
        }


    al.remove(al.size()-1);
    cl.remove(cl.size()-1);
    tl.remove(tl.size()-1);
    lineEnd.remove(lineEnd.size()-1);
    juncture.remove(juncture.size()-1);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

P.S., I have a for loop in there because if you press it once, the change on the painting is minute.

Comment: That isn't surprising. What data type is redo? An Array of ArrayLists?

Comment: Can you post the exception and stacktrace you get? Also, how do you set the values in redo?

Comment: static ArrayList<Shape> al = new ArrayList<Shape>();
 static ArrayList<Color> cl = new ArrayList<Color>();
 static ArrayList<Integer> tl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 static ArrayList<Integer> lineEnd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 static ArrayList<Integer> juncture = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes; is that a problem?           EDIT: Solved the problem by removing the array of arraylist and creating each new array for the redo data :) Thanks guys

Comment: @gedr Not in and of itself. You need to check there is an element, before attempting to remove it. Not posting the relevant variable definition or stacktrace with your question....

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks Elliot, from your directions I managed to solve the problem! I will try to make my new question more clear, with precise and relevant information. Sorry for that. I am new to all of this...

Answer (score 1):

Inside your redo loop, you

1. check that there is a redo-able item and redo if you can, then
2. (unconditionally) remove an item from the redo lists

Move the `remove()`s into the if block.

Also, don't use five arrays.  Create a class that does all that for you, with well-named redo lists.  (That's just a tip, has nothing to do with your question.)